# How to integrate jersey with guice and bean validation

Tags: validation, rest, jersey, javabeans, guice

I'm using jersey + guice for developing REST application. I'd like to make input validation for query params but what I'm looking for is a 'ready-to-use' solution rather than writing it by myself.

I've already found [support](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/bean-validation.html) for bean validation with jersey but unfortunately have no 
idea how to integrate it with guice. Most of the validation I need to do is simple @NotNull checking. I need to validate the value and return a detailed message when validation fails.

Any ideas? Suggestions?

Comment: This also enables integration of Guice + Hibernate Validator: https://github.com/xvik/guice-validator I've just confirmed it works fine with  that combo + Jersey:

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've worked it out.

Instead of using glassfish extension to jersey I used apache bean validation. Following dependencies are required to be added to project (gradle way):

```
compile 'org.apache.bval:bval-guice:0.5'
compile 'javax.validation:validation-api:1.1.0.Final'
```

While creating guice injector following module should be added:

```
org.apache.bval.guice.ValidationModule
```

Here's how mapper looks like (groovy)

```
import com.google.inject.Singleton

import javax.validation.ConstraintViolationException
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response
import javax.ws.rs.ext.ExceptionMapper
import javax.ws.rs.ext.Provider

import static groovy.json.JsonOutput.toJson
import static javax.ws.rs.core.Response.Status.BAD_REQUEST
import static javax.ws.rs.core.Response.status

@Provider
@Singleton
class ValidationExceptionMapper implements ExceptionMapper {

    @Override
    Response toResponse(ConstraintViolationException e) {
        status(BAD_REQUEST).entity(toJson(e.constraintViolations*.message)).build()
    }
}
```

Exception mapper must be bound in any guice module with simple bind() method. 
Then method with parameters to be validated should be marked with:

```
org.apache.bval.guice.Validate
```

And a parameter for instance with:

```
javax.validation.constraints.NotNull
```

That's all.

Comment: This answer really saved my bacon.  Thank you very much, BTW, you don't have to manually "bind()" the ExceptionMapper if it's part of a package that's included with / passed to the ResourceConfig.

Comment: You're welcome. I guess it's enough to use `@Singleton` annotation.

Comment: If you are a Jersey 1.x user, beside the aforementioned `org.apache.bval.guice.Validate` annotation on your method, you also need the regular `javax.validation.Valid` annotation before your bean parameter.

Comment: Thanks @DanielOlszewski!